# How to parse huge XML file with various elements in Go?

Tags: go

How can you parse a huge XML file that's having various elements (i.e. not same element repeated multiple times).

Example:

```
<stuff>
    <header>...</header>
    <item>...</item>
    ...
    <item>...</item>
    <something>...</sometihng>
</stuff>
```

I want to write a script in Go that would allow me to split this file in multiple smaller files with specific amount of tags per file.
All examples on how to parse XML with Go seems to rely on knowing the elements that you have in the file.

Can the file be parsed without knowing that? Something like for each element in XML no matter what element is there (header, item, something, etc...)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the standard [xml Decoder](https://godoc.org/encoding/xml#Decoder).

Call [Token](https://godoc.org/encoding/xml#Decoder.Token) to read tokens one by one. When a start element of interest is found, call [DecodeElement](https://godoc.org/encoding/xml#Decoder.DecodeElement) to decode the element to a Go value.

Here's a sketch of how to use the decoder:

```
d := xml.NewDecoder(r)
for {
    t, tokenErr := d.Token()
    if tokenErr != nil {
        if tokenErr == io.EOF {
           break
        }
        // handle error somehow
        return fmt.Errorf("decoding token: %v", err)
    }
    switch t := t.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:
        if t.Name.Space == "foo" && t.Name.Local == "bar" {
            var b bar
            if err := d.DecodeElement(&b, &t); err != nil {
                // handle error somehow
                return fmt.Errorf("decoding element %q: %v", t.Name.Local, err)
            }
            // do something with b
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any hints on how to know distinguish end of file from actual error? Is there some defined error value for EOF to compare with? Because I handle errors with panics or log.Fatal, and this is not the best way to exit loops.

Comment: Ah, never mind it is just me being an go noob. Break loop if error is `io.EOF` else handle error.

Comment: What if I want to give the whole xpath to search for an element because using above method it will fetch first occurrence of that element what about next occurrence of `bar`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much a limit of Go as a limit of xml.  XML elements only make sense according to their schema (which predefines what elements are in other elements).

Answer (score 1):

You should look to SAX parses, something like https://github.com/kokardy/saxlike

Comment: If I ask "how to program?" would you code me an example? The link I gave has examples & source codes.

Can the file be parsed without knowing that? YES. Something like for each element in XML no matter what element is there (header, item, something, etc...) - YES. The answer is to the point of question.

Answer (score 0):

you can also check following library which has been tested with big xml files. It has  written to address the performance [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21823) in go default xml package.

[xml stream parser](https://github.com/tamerh/xml-stream-parser)